# LibSVM weights of support vectors

Tags: machine-learning

I am using `LibSVM` classifier in my Java code and I am getting correct results as I verified that with weka GUI, however, when I want to get the weights of the support vectors, I get an empty string. This is a snapshot of my code:

```
LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
svm.buildClassifier(train_data);
Evaluation evaluation = null;
evaluation = new Evaluation (train_data);
evaluation.crossValidateModel(svm, train_data, 10, new Random(1));
System.out.println("weights = "+ svm.getWeights());
```

So, I am wondering if there is any missing step that I should do in using the `LibSVM` so that I get the weights?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyze the generated model file by svm-train. This is explained in the FAQ [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) and [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402). Concretely, you access the alpha though the sv_coefs members of the class svm_model.

Answer (score 0):

I remember LibSVM uses RBF as default kernel, so you can't really have feature weights, since the solution is in the dual. Try changing to linear kernel, that should get you some weights out.

Comment: Actually, I want the alpha vector not the weights (that was a mistake). If you can help me in that I really appreciate.

Comment: @Tarfa you should edit your question, this information is relevant in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the model file by calling the method:
libsvm.setModelFile(filename);
and you will find all the alpha vector values and support vector values in this model file after running the classifier.